# findBy property in List<Object> SpringBoot JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many, findby

I have a one to many relationship between two objects in my database Story and Tag.

I'm looking to to be able to get all Story objects that have a Tag object with the String name.

Story.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stories")
public class Story  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"story"})
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "story", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Tag> tags;

    public Story(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Story(){

    }

// getters & setters

}
```

Tag.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"tags"})
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "story_id", nullable = false)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Story story;

    public Tag(String name, Story story){
        this.name = name;
        this.story = story;
    }

    public Tag(){

    }

/// getters & setters

}
```

StoryController.java

```
@RestController
public class StoryController {
    @Autowired
    StoryRepository storyRepository;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/api")
    @GetMapping(value = "/stories")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Story>> getAllStories(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(storyRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/api")
    @GetMapping(value="/stories/tagSearch/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<Story> getStoryByTag(@PathVariable String name) {
        return new ResponseEntity(storyRepository.findByTags_Name(name), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080/api")
    @GetMapping(value="/stories/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Story> getStory(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity(storyRepository.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

StoryRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface StoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Story, Long> {

    public List<Story> findByTags_Name(String name);

}
```

When trying to query through the browser, going to the address localhost:8080/api/stories/tagSearch/?name="tag" the database returns all objects in the database rather than the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the below method in your `repository`.

```
public List<Story> findByTagsName(String name);
```

You need to use the following URL to fetch the details, as you have defined the `name` as `PathVariable`

```
localhost:8080/api/stories/tagSearch/tag
```

tag - is your name

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your repository

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Story s left join s.tags t WHERE t.name = ?1")
public List<Story> findByTags_Name(String name);
```